# How to auto-populate a form on a site using the i made on another html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, auto-populate

I have a site that I want to auto-populate using a certain web page I made. I want to fill my own field on my site and if I click auto-populate, the information inputted on my page will auto-populate the site that I'm targeting.

This is necessary so that we will not be inputting twice because I'm doing note takings on the page that I've made.

I have searched the web for this problem but I could not find the answer. Can you please help me?

Comment: which programming language are u using PHP, ASP.NET (server side..) etc

Comment: i am using just pure html coding and some scripting. can i be able to do this procedure using simple methods? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Using Javascript

This [scriptinglink](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111) will be useful to your problem ... passing and receiving using Javascript :).. please checkout.

One more helpful [link](http://www.cryer.co.uk/resources/javascript/script8.htm)

> Using Server Side Language

and if you wanna use some server side language (php) ... this [phplink](http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson11.php) will b useful